# What is the best way to learn Wing Chun?

Tags: wing-chun

Can anybody give me some hints on learning Wing Chun? Some tutorials, Youtube channels, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can learn some forms and some strikes from watching video... but you won't learn the stuff that makes Wing Chun effective from video.  A lot of Wing Chun's strength is sensitivity to the opponent, adapting to trap their arms, and force generation at short range.  The problem, too, is that you might see "I put my arm here" when you copy the form, but you won't know "I focus the pressure of my arm HERE" which is the trickiness to Wing Chun.

What a class or instruction gives you, that a video doesn't, is being able to feel movement, angles, and feeling someone skilled cut through your defense and pick up those tricks yourself.  Likewise, very few videos go into the conditioning that the art does as well, which is the other half of what you need to generate power in your strikes.

If you can get someone who can at least teach you and a couple of folks the basic sticky-hands drills (for a few days or weeks), you can get something from your effort, because you'll have a live drill you can do on your own to get sensitivity.

Answer (score 5):

Find and enroll in a wing chun school, then in a year test your skills in a full-contact competition.

Tutorials are for learning how to set up your programming development environment. YouTube channels are for entertainment. Neither are training. Training is becoming an athlete by working out, learning skills, and entering competitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but...I'm in Romania and here are not many Wing Chun or Kung Fu schools,or here are no such schools at all,just a few schools of box and karate...Anyway,I'll search a little more,maybe I will find one.

Comment: You can't study an art if there's no school nearby. For your situation I would recommend boxing.  Boxing is good stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Dave Liepmann, that the only real way to learn a martial art is to have a teacher who can guide you. And you need to do it two or three times a week.

But, let me offer a small amount of hope for you to learn wing-chun if you have no teacher present and no school around. If I was in your situation, and I knew that wing-chun was the only martial art I wanted to learn, no exceptions, then I would contact others near me that also wanted to learn, and we would form a group.

Our group would contact a well respected wing-chun school (for example Leung Ting's school), and would email the instructor or their representatives. We would ask if one or more of us could come and train for, maybe, 2 weeks at a time from 9AM to 5PM doing private lessons. It would be a kind of "accelerated learning" program / "crash course". If they accepted, we would fly there and train for those 2 weeks and then fly back home. Then at home, we would continue to train with each other, doing as best we could, correcting each other and continuing to practice 2 to 3 times per week.

At some point, say, 6 months or a year later (the sooner the better), we could fly there again and train for another 2 weeks. Repeat.

It all depends on how willing you are to travel, how much time you have, and how much you're willing to pay.

I don't recommend doing this alone, by the way. Without a group to train with, you are stuck doing solo forms and wooden dummy stuff. That stuff is okay, but it's not very useful. And you would be missing out on a lot of other things. If that's all you want, then do it. Otherwise, form a group first. Then each of you can use each other to practice with and help each other.

Not all of you in your group needs to travel, by the way. The more the better. But those that do not travel will just need to be trained by those that did travel. That can work out pretty well. You could even take turns traveling, to keep costs low and to learn more quickly.

So if you have 4 members in your group, 2 of you could go now, and the other 2 could go 6 months from now. That way, you learn twice as much as you would if all 4 of you would go only once per year. This is something you can work out amongst yourselves.

As for online courses and DVD, yes that is possible. You can learn all of the forms and wooden dummy stuff that way. But the chi-sao (partnered exercises) are not something that you can learn that way. You need an instructor to teach it to you in person and correct you. And you need a partner. And you need to do it frequently.

Anyway, those are my thoughts on the subject. You mentioned having boxing gyms near you. I would try that first, if I were you. You might discover that you enjoy it a lot. Boxing is also something that seems to work in MMA competition and street fighting.

Oh, and by the way, you might also want to look for either Judo or Brazilian Jiujitsu schools near you. Judo is pretty popular. And BJJ is getting to be popular now (in some parts of the world, it's much more popular than Judo is). Combine that with boxing, and you have a pretty good combination.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you will find 100's of video tutorial of wing chun in this link

http://www.youtube.com/user/138mws/playlists

Comment: But is watching videos a good way to learn Wing Chun?

Comment: i think so.. because i am learing taichi yang from the same videos since.. 7 month..

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are unable to actually attend a Wing Chun school I would recommend getting a Muk Yan Jong to practice on. It helps with technique application and forearm strengthening. If you build your own they're not too expensive (50 US dollars) and take about a weekend to build.

Answer (score 0):

Find a **good** teacher - and a good group to train with. 
This is important for all martial arts, especially for internal styles.
(I recommend training wing chun as internal martial art)

As an edit, I should outline: what is a good quality in a teacher?

1. He/She should not have the need to show that he is better/stronger than you. You already know that. That's the reason you train with him.
2. He should train **with** you.
3. He should be able to explain why a technique works or not. He should be able to explain the mechanics within the bounds of your limitations (these should decease over time).
4. He should challenge you from time to time, but inside your capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Emin Boztepe has trained in Wing Tsun for decades. He has a brand of his own called Emin Boztepe Martial Arts System (EBMAS). He trained under Leung Ting and Keith Kernspecht. You will definitely learn how to fight in this system. There are 2 schools in Romania under his system. Here is a link to the info for those schools:

[EBMAS schools in Romania](http://www.ebmas.net/category/schule/romania/?lang=en)